# The requested contract could not be found

Tags: solidity

I am currently working on a project which consists of 5 smart contracts namely HOPTOKNToken.sol, HOPTOKNContract.sol, HGTOKNToken.sol, MyGovernance.sol and HGTOKNContract.sol

I have created a truffle project and I am trying to deploy all these smart contracts on Matic testnet. The first 4 contracts are being deployed but when it comes to HGOTKNContract.sol, it throws an error that the requested contract could not be found.

Below are the necessary codes

HGTOKNContract.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.3;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/access/OwnableUpgradeable.sol";

import "./HGTOKNToken.sol";
import "./HOPTOKNContract.sol"; 
 
contract HGTOKNContract is OwnableUpgradeable {
    HGTOKNToken public token; // HGTOKNToken contract instance
    string public name; // Contract name
    address adminWalletAddress; // Address of the contract deployer
    address public hoptoknContractAddress; // Address of the HOPTOKNContract
    HOPTOKNContract public hoptoknContract; // HOPTOKNContract instance

    uint256 public stakingPeriod; // Staking period in seconds
    uint256 public hoptoknRewardRate; // Reward rate of HOPTOKN tokens

    uint public poolTotalSupply; // Total supply of HGTOKN tokens in the pool
    uint public poolOfStakes; // Total amount of HGTOKN tokens staked in the pool
    uint256 public stakingEndTime; // End time of the staking period

    struct Staker {
        uint256 stakedBalance; // Amount of HGTOKN tokens staked by the user
        uint256 lastStakeTime; // Timestamp of the last stake
    }

    mapping(address => Staker) public stakers; // Mapping to store staker information

    event Staked(address indexed user, uint256 amount); // Event emitted when a user stakes HGTOKN tokens
    event Withdrawn(address indexed user, uint256 amount); // Event emitted when a user unstakes HGTOKN tokens
    event HoptoknRewardPaid(address indexed user, uint256 amount); // Event emitted when a user receives HOPTOKN rewards

    function storeConstructor(
        HGTOKNToken _token,
        string memory _name,
        uint _tokenTotalSupply,
        address _hoptoknContractAddress
    ) public initializer {
        token = _token;
        name = _name; // Get the contract name from HGTOKNToken
        adminWalletAddress = msg.sender;
        hoptoknContractAddress = _hoptoknContractAddress;
        hoptoknContract = HOPTOKNContract(_hoptoknContractAddress);
        stakingPeriod = 15 days; // Default staking period is 15 days
        hoptoknRewardRate = 1000000000000000000; // Default reward rate is 1 HOPTOKN token
        poolTotalSupply = _tokenTotalSupply;
    }

    function stake(uint256 _amount) external {
        require(_amount > 0, "Amount must be greater than 0");
        require(
            token.balanceOf(msg.sender) >= _amount,
            "Insufficient HGTOKN balance"
        );

        Staker storage staker = stakers[msg.sender];
        staker.stakedBalance += _amount;
        staker.lastStakeTime = block.timestamp;
        stakingEndTime = block.timestamp + stakingPeriod; // Set the end time of the staking period

        // Transfer the staked HGTOKN tokens from the user to the contract
        token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);

        // Update the poolOfStakes
        poolOfStakes += _amount;

        emit Staked(msg.sender, _amount);
    }

    function unstake() external {
        Staker storage staker = stakers[msg.sender];
        require(staker.stakedBalance > 0, "No staked balance");
        require(block.timestamp >= stakingEndTime, "Staking period not ended"); // Check if staking period has ended

        // Return the staked HGTOKN tokens to the staker's wallet
        token.transfer(msg.sender, staker.stakedBalance);

        // Update the poolOfStakes
        poolOfStakes -= staker.stakedBalance;

        emit Withdrawn(msg.sender, staker.stakedBalance);

        // Reset the staker's information
        staker.stakedBalance = 0;
        staker.lastStakeTime = 0;
        stakingEndTime = 0; // Reset the staking end time
    }

    function claimReward() external {
        Staker storage staker = stakers[msg.sender];
        require(staker.stakedBalance > 0, "No stake balance");

        if (block.timestamp >= stakingEndTime) { // Only pay rewards if staking period has ended
            uint256 timeSinceLastStake = block.timestamp - staker.lastStakeTime;
            uint256 reward = (timeSinceLastStake / stakingPeriod) * hoptoknRewardRate;

            if (reward > 0) {
                // Transfer the reward amount of HOPTOKN tokens from the Ecosystem Pool to the staker
                hoptoknContract.transferFromEcosystemPool(msg.sender, reward);

                emit HoptoknRewardPaid(msg.sender, reward);
            }
        }

        // Update the staker's last stake time
        staker.lastStakeTime = block.timestamp;
    }

    function updateStakingPeriod(uint256 _stakingPeriod) external onlyOwner {
        require(_stakingPeriod > 0, "Invalid staking period");
        stakingPeriod = _stakingPeriod;
    }

    function updateHoptoknRewardRate(uint256 _hoptoknRewardRate) external onlyOwner {
        hoptoknRewardRate = _hoptoknRewardRate;
    }

    function transferHGTOKN(address _recipient, uint256 _amount) external onlyOwner {
        require(_recipient != address(0), "Invalid recipient address");
        require(_amount > 0, "Amount must be greater than 0");
        require(
            token.balanceOf(address(this)) >= _amount,
            "Insufficient HGTOKN balance"
        );

        token.transfer(_recipient, _amount);

        poolTotalSupply -= _amount;
    }

    function getHgtoknBalance() external view returns (uint256) {
        return token.balanceOf(address(this));
    }

    function getHoptoknBalance() external view returns (uint256) {
        return hoptoknContract.getBalance();
    }

    function getPoolOfStakes() external view returns (uint256) {
        return poolOfStakes;
    }

    function getPoolTotalSupply() external view returns (uint256) {
        return poolTotalSupply;
    }
}
```

2_deploy_contracts.js

```
const HOPTOKNToken = artifacts.require("HOPTOKNToken");
const HOPTOKNContract = artifacts.require("HOPTOKNContract");
const HGTOKNToken = artifacts.require("HGTOKNToken");
const HGTOKNContract = artifacts.require("HGTOKNContract");
const MyGovernor = artifacts.require("MyGovernor");

const { deployProxy } = require('@openzeppelin/truffle-upgrades');

module.exports = async function (deployer) {
  console.log("Deploying...");

  // Deploy HOPTOKNToken
  await deployer.deploy(HOPTOKNToken);
  const hoptoknToken = await HOPTOKNToken.deployed();
  let hoptoknTokenTotalSupply = await hoptoknToken.totalSupply();

  console.log("HOPTOKNToken Deployed To: ", hoptoknToken.address);

  //Deploy HOPTOKNContract
  let hoptoknContract = await deployProxy(HOPTOKNContract, [
    hoptoknToken.address,
    "HOPTOKN",
    hoptoknTokenTotalSupply
  ], { deployer, initializer: 'storeConstructor' });

  await hoptoknToken.transfer(hoptoknContract.address, hoptoknTokenTotalSupply);

  console.log("HOPTOKNContract Deployed To: ", hoptoknContract.address);

  // Deploy HGTOKNToken
  await deployer.deploy(HGTOKNToken);
  const hgtoknToken = await HGTOKNToken.deployed();
  let hgtoknTokenTotalSupply = await hgtoknToken.totalSupply();

  console.log("HGTOKNToken Deployed To:", hgtoknToken.address);

  // Deploy MyGovernor
  await deployer.deploy(MyGovernor, hgtoknToken.address);
  const myGovernor = await MyGovernor.deployed();

  console.log("MyGovernor Deployed To:", myGovernor.address);

  //Deploy HOPTOKNContract
  let hgtoknContract = await deployProxy(HGTOKNContract, [
    hgtoknToken.address,
    "HGTOKN",
    hgtoknTokenTotalSupply,
    hoptoknContract.address
  ], { deployer, initializer: 'storeConstructor' });

  console.log("HGTOKNContract Deployed To:", hgtoknContract.address);

  console.log("HOPTOKNToken Deployed To:", hoptoknToken.address);
  console.log("HOPTOKNContract Deployed To:", hoptoknContract.address);
  console.log("HGTOKNToken Deployed To:", hgtoknToken.address);
  console.log("MyGovernor Deployed To:", myGovernor.address);
  console.log("HGTOKNContract Deployed To:", hgtoknContract.address);
};
```

truffle-config.js

```
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");

const fs = require("fs");
const projectID = "e72f201c37d44f64be1b1c39bf3fe0c1";
const accountPrivatekey = "af542020c6730bc71cd814017f41cd9c8a676235cc216807f4a074b788a8fbf6";

const mnemonic = "citizen glory edit crop science razor course cool sadness scheme segment action";

module.exports = {
  contracts_directory: './contracts/',
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*", // Match any network id
    },
    matic: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `wss://polygon-mumbai.g.alchemy.com/v2/HqbFhBlYqgD82jxUVkSAdA2wHjZdI-cL`),
      network_id: 80001,
      confirmations: 2,
      timeoutBlocks: 200000,
      skipDryRun: true
    },
/*       ethmain: {
        networkCheckTimeout: 500000,
        // from: "0x3997d3AccEBad60EbAe81B2191F81f9055b3B420",
        provider: () =>
          new HDWalletProvider(
            accountPrivatekey,
            `https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/749b4bfa06184014b40df76938f06da6`
          ),
        network_id: 1,
        confirmations: 5,
        timeoutBlocks: 200,
        skipDryRun: true,
      }, */
/*     bsctestnet: {
      networkCheckTimeout: 1500000,
      // from: "0x3997d3AccEBad60EbAe81B2191F81f9055b3B420",
      // provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(accountPrivatekey, `wss://data-seed-prebsc-1-s2.binance.org:8545`),
      provider: () =>
        new HDWalletProvider(
          accountPrivatekey,
          `https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545`
        ),
      network_id: 97,
      confirmations: 2,
      timeoutBlocks: 200000,
      skipDryRun: true,
      gasPrice: 50000000000,
    }, */
/*     goerli: {
      networkCheckTimeout: 500000,
      provider: () =>
        new HDWalletProvider(
          accountPrivatekey,
          "wss://goerli.infura.io/ws/v3/a9408e5619eb436796b761bbc2e61200"
        ),
      network_id: 5, // Ropsten's id
      confirmations: 2, // # of confs to wait between deployments. (default: 0)
      timeoutBlocks: 200, // # of blocks before a deployment times out  (minimum/default: 50)
      skipDryRun: true, // Skip dry run before migrations? (default: false for public nets )
    }, */
/*     bscmain: {
      from: "0x1aEFEe98a7861c65cC4D14B4f9d6C75EF2150562",
      networkCheckTimeout: 100000,
      // wss://bsc-ws-node.nariox.org:443
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(accountPrivatekey, `https://bsc.getblock.io/463c1971-48d0-47ad-bea9-3f41d7c79ae8/mainnet/`),
      network_id: 56,
      confirmations: 5,
      timeoutBlocks: 200,
      skipDryRun: true
    }, */
/*     mumbai_polygon: {
      provider: () =>
        new HDWalletProvider(
          accountPrivatekey,
          `https://polygon-mumbai.g.alchemy.com/v2/QJwTxuA9PB10v0nFniTosad3S6CYr8kM`
        ),
      network_id: 80001,
      confirmations: 2,
      timeoutBlocks: 200,
      skipDryRun: true,
    }, */
  },

  // Set default mocha options here, use special reporters etc.
  mocha: {
    // timeout: 100000
  },

  // Configure your compilers
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.8.19", // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
      // docker: true,        // Use "0.5.1" you've installed locally with docker (default: false)
       settings: {
         // See the solidity docs for advice about optimization and evmVersion
         optimizer: {
           enabled: true,
           runs: 200,
         },
      //   evmVersion: "byzantium",
       },
    },
  },
};
```

I have tried deleting the builds folder, changing node and truffle versions, re adding the truffles-upgrade plugin and updating all the plugins as well. I don't even know if the logic in HGTOKNContract is correct for my needs and that needs to be check as well but for that I need to deploy it so that my react frontend could interact with the smart contract. I know this is type of question was already asked 2 years back but it didn't solve my issue. Please help me. Thanks!

The error:

Exiting: Review successful transactions manually by checking the transaction hashes above on Etherscan.

Error: The requested contract was not found. Make sure the source code is available for compilation

```
at getContractNameAndRunValidation (C:\Users\yashg\Desktop\Hopabot\HGTOKNContract\node_modules\@openzeppelin\upgrades-core\src\validate\query.ts:75:11)
at getStorageLayout (C:\Users\yashg\Desktop\Hopabot\HGTOKNContract\node_modules\@openzeppelin\upgrades-core\src\validate\query.ts:83:45)
at getDeployData (C:\Users\yashg\Desktop\Hopabot\HGTOKNContract\node_modules\@openzeppelin\truffle-upgrades\src\utils\deploy-impl.ts:45:34)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at deployProxyImpl (C:\Users\yashg\Desktop\Hopabot\HGTOKNContract\node_modules\@openzeppelin\truffle-upgrades\src\utils\deploy-impl.ts:64:22)
at deployProxy (C:\Users\yashg\Desktop\Hopabot\HGTOKNContract\node_modules\@openzeppelin\truffle-upgrades\src\deploy-proxy.ts:36:26)
at module.exports (C:\Users\yashg\Desktop\Hopabot\HGTOKNContract\migrations\2_deploy_contracts.js:44:24)
```

Truffle v5.10.2 (core: 5.10.2)
Node v18.16.1

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

1. Could you please put a picture of your folder structure, specifically where the contracts are? That would help.
2. Hope you ran `truffle compile`.
3. Hope you are using the node LTS version. If not, please do. Keep the version of Truffle as the latest one (IMP).
4. In your `truffle-config.js` file, remove the following line:

   ```
   contracts_directory: './contracts/'
   ```

   Replace it with this line:

   ```
   contracts_build_directory: "./truffle-artifacts"
   ```

   Meaning that - you need to make a folder named `truffle-artifacts` in your project's root directly. After you compile your smart contracts, the ABI will be present in this directory, separate from your project's build directory (if any).
5. After that, do `truffle build` and then `truffle compile`. The issue should be solved.
6. Also, if possible use Solidity Compiler Version 0.8.18. Seems far more stable than any other version to me to date.

Comment: I have a main folder named HGTOKNContract in which I have placed all the 5 smart contracts inside the contracts folder. Also, I tried all your solutions but the error is still being thrown. It might be an issue with the deployment script itself because when I try to deploy using Hardhat, it works fine but I want to deploy only Truffle only

Comment: Okay. Could you please provide the deployment script?

Comment: Hey there, I have successfully deployed using Hardhat itself as there seems to be a bug while using Truffle. Although, I still have a few more issues to be fixed which I will send down below